# You may be attempting to write into another users folder which is not supported

Tags: windows-server-2003, flash, permissions

Why do I get this message when trying to compile a file in Flash MX 2004?

"If you are logged in with a limited user account, then you may be attempting to write into another users folder which is not supported."

The folder and files are owned by the Administrators group; however, the user trying to modify the files is a member of a group which is inheriting permissions to have full control over the files, except take ownership and change permissions.

Why would a user, whose effective permissions include virtually everything, be unable to write to a file... and end up getting an error message like the one described?

Comment: I had the user log off their session and log back on.  Everything works now.  So I suspect the permissions were right all along.  It was just all of the sudden he couldn't write to files in a few of the folders inside his work folder.  Logging off and back on again fixed the problem.  Any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a UAC prompt.  Your tags say server 2003, is that actually the OS of the machine that you are trying to compile the file on?

EDIT:
If the message is coming from Flash then for whatever reason it couldn't write to the file.  (I guess the message has been written like that because they are fed up with support calls from users who are using Vista and UAC is blocking their attempt to save somewhere odd.)  So, my guess is that another process had the file locked, especially as it was fixed by loggin off and on again.  There is a program called WhoLockMe that can tell you which process has locks on a particular file.  Its a good utility to have around.
This http://www.dr-hoiby.com/WhoLockMe/ appears to be the app I am talking about.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought too that it sounded like UAC... but this is a message coming from FlashMX 2004, and I guess a non-administrator is a standard user on windows server 2003.

Comment: I have added my suggestions to my answer given what you said in your comment.  You would normally edit your question if you have more information, not hide it in the comments.

Comment: Flash MX 2004 was released long before Vista and UAC, so they couldn't have made the message for Vista's UAC... it's clearly talking about limited user accounts in Windows Server 2003. I posted in the comments, because it describes a solution, not the problem. It's not a file lock, because it happened to entire folders, randomly, many which were never being edited in any way, and I use process explorer to check for open file handles, and the only programs holding an open handle is flash itself and "System".

Comment: The real puzzle is why "System" has an open file handle to some of these files, because none of them are open on any machine that uses those folders.  I'm guessing it's some kind of bug in windows where the system is not properly closing file handles, or it's opening them for some reason where it shouldn't be.